# SwitchCompat fontfamily won't change

Tags: android, switchcompat

I'm using Android Studio and have a SwitchCompat widget in my main activity. The default fontfamily it had was sans-serif-medium and I changed it to quicksand_light. I also have some TextViews with each of their fontfamily's set to quicksand_light. On the design tab of the xml file for my activity it shows the SwitchCompat having the quicksand_light fontfamily just as the TextViews, but when I run it on my phone or on an emulator the SwitchCompat's fontfamily is sans-serif-medium. Is there something extra I need to do to change the fontfamily or is this a bug or is this just me?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't dived deep into why it's not working correctly when defining the `fontFamily` attribute in xml, but **IT WORKS** if you set the typeface **programmatically**.

Here's an example using data-binding.

Add the following data-binding adapter:

```
@BindingAdapter("labelTypeface")
fun setLabelTypeface(view: SwitchCompat, @FontRes id: Int) {
    view.typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(view.context, id)
}
```

and use it in your layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:labelTypeface="@{R.font.stratum}"
    ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've been able to set the font family on the switch's thumb (not its label) is with:

```java
    my_switch.setSwitchTypeface(ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.my_font))
```